# JqueryUI progressbar value in a span

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, progress-bar

I am want to display the value in a span but i am stuck how to do this.

This is my Javascript:

```
$(".progressbar-count").each(function() {
    $(this).progressbar({
        value: parseInt($(this).attr("value"))
    }), $(".progressbar-count .ui-progressbar-value").animate({
        width: 0
    }, 0).stop().animate({
        width: $(".progressbar-count").attr("value")
    }, 3500)
});
```

As you can see i have the progressbar animated so the value in the span must count with the animated progressbar.

And my HTML:

```
<span class="percent"></span>
<div class="progressbar-count" value="100%"></div>
```

Comment: hmm... you want this: http://jsfiddle.net/bvxej/ but with the span going from 0-100% with the progress bar?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this http://jsfiddle.net/Tentonaxe/tePc3/, it uses an easing plugin built by Ben Nadel at http://www.bennadel.com/blog/2007-Using-jQuery-s-animate-Method-To-Power-Easing-Based-Iteration.htm

The power of google at work.

Comment: Updated to a more optimized version

Comment: One question now when i put 50% in the value the progressbar go's to 100%? How can i change this?

Answer (score 0):

>

Show Value:
$j("#progressBar").children('span.caption').html($j( "#progressBar" ).progressbar( "value" ) + "%");

Comment: After posting in a better format, you might want to delete this post.

Answer (score 0):

```
<div id="progressBar">
<span class="caption" style="position:absolute;margin-left: 5%;margin-top: -5px;">
</span>
</div>

$j("#progressBar").children('span.caption').html($j( "#progressBar" ).progressbar( "value" ) + "%");
```